# Remove hours from time series

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Dygraphs allows easy display of time series...

However, if my data contains only two data points, it automatically fills the gaps in X axis with hours. Is it possible to disable this functionality?
I searched and tried many options but not found anything useful.

Example might be the 'Time Series Drawing Demo' from the gallery - if executed on only few datapoints, it fills the 'gaps' with hours.

This is a good example:

```
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById('plot'),"a,b\n2008-12-01,0.9\n2008-12-02,0.3\n2008-12-03,0.7\n")
```

UPDATE-  this seems to be working:

```
ticker: function(a, b, pixels, opts, dygraph, vals) {
  var chosen = Dygraph.pickDateTickGranularity(a, b, pixels, opts);
  if(chosen==12) chosen=13;
  if (chosen >= 0) {
    return Dygraph.getDateAxis(a, b, chosen, opts, dygraph);
  } else {
    // this can happen if self.width_ is zero.
    return [];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not that you have two points, but that your points cover a certain amount of time. Dygraphs tries to calculate the best granularity for the x axis tick marks in a given set of data.

One way to modify the default calculation is by using the [pixelsPerLabel](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#pixelsPerLabel) option.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kaliatech/P8ehg/

```
var data = "a,b\n2008-12-01,0.9\n2008-12-02,0.3\n2008-12-03,0.7\n";
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("plot"), data, {
  axes: {
    x: {
        pixelsPerLabel: 100
      }
    }
});
```

This requires hard coding a pixel width though, and it is still ultimately dependent on the data set that you are graphing.  A more flexible approach might be to use the [ticker](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#ticker) option, allowing you to supply your own function for calculating label granularity. See the documentation and built-in functions of [dygraph-tickers.js](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/dygraph-tickers.js).

See also:

- [How to set specific y-axis label points in dygraphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481437/how-to-set-specific-y-axis-label-points-in-dygraphs)

---

EDIT: Example using ticker. This requires that you are familiar with the data and the data range is somewhat constant, otherwise you could end up with unreadable x-axis labels.

```
var g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("demodiv3"), data(), {
  title: 'Example for changing x-axis label granularity 3',
  axes: {
    x: {
        ticker: function(a, b, pixels, opts, dygraph, vals) {
          var chosen = Dygraph.pickDateTickGranularity(a, b, pixels, opts);
          //Force to DAILY if built-in calculation returned SIX_HOURLY
            //if(chosen==Dygraph.SIX_HOURLY)
            //    chosen=Dygraph.DAILY;
          //or

          //Force to DAILY always
          chosen = Dygraph.DAILY;

          if (chosen >= 0) {
            return Dygraph.getDateAxis(a, b, chosen, opts, dygraph);
          } else {
            return [];
          }
        }        
      }

    }
});
```

Comment: axisLabelFormatter seems to disable hours when called as Dygraph.dateAxisFormatter(d,Dygraph.DAILY) but still fills too many intermediate tickers...

Comment: Not clear what your question is at this point, and depends on what you want.  The ticker sample you edited in to your question will force the granularity to DAILY, but only when the built-in calculation determines that SIX_HOURLY would be ideal.  Depending on your data, maybe that's sufficient, or maybe instead you want to force to DAILY regardless.  In any case, I would suggest using Dygraph.SIX_HOURLY & Dygraph.DAILY instead of 12 and 13 in your code to make it more readable.

Comment: I edited my answer (and the jsfiddle) to show example using ticker.