# How to change the parameters of axes in dygraph

Tags: javascript, pug, dygraphs

I am using dygraph for my project. I am able to generate the graphs, but I want the time instead of date on my *x* axis. How can I achieve this?

Basically I will be running my test every hour instead of running each day that's why I want *x* axis to be in time not in date.

Here is the screenshot of my dygraph:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

First of all, you could make your charts wider. dygraphs has calculated that there's not enough space on the x-axis to show hourly or daily ticks, so it fell back to weekly ticks.

If you want to force dygraphs to show hourly ticks, you could do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18339691/388951):

```
var g = new Dygraph(div, data, {
  axes: {
    x: {
      ticker: function(a, b, pixels, opts, dygraph, vals) {
        return Dygraph.getDateAxis(a, b, Dygraph.HOURLY, opts, dygraph);
        // or TWO_HOURLY or SIX_HOURLY...
      }        
    }
  }
});
```